# Procedural textures in 3d View

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm having trouble showing procedural textures (Checker Texture in particular) in 3d View. I can see it in render, but neither Material/Texture/Solid viewport shading helps to see in 3D :(
[This](http://c2n.me/3wTKCNW) is a screenshot with my issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. As long as there is no image file being used for texturing, you will not see results in other modes than *rendered*.